# Create list names dynamically from for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm try to scrape book descriptions of books listed on Choice awards on Goodreads.
I'm using the following function to get the individual urls listed for a specific genre

```
def get_genre_url(genre):    
    all_links = []

    for year in (range(2011,2022)):        
        url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/choiceawards/best-' + genre + '-books-'+ str(year)        
        page = requests.get(url) 
        soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser') 
        for link in soup.find_all('a',  {'class':'pollAnswer__bookLink'}):                
            all_links.append('https://www.goodreads.com' + link.get('href'))
                
    return(all_links)
```

After I get the books urls I continue with scrapping of these urls to get to the book description.

```
def get_description(genre_list):
    
    urls = []
    authors = []
    titles = []
    index = 0
    
    for url in genre_list:
        #print(index,url)

        page = requests.get(url)    
        soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')    

        authors.append(soup.find('title').get_text().split(' by ')[1])
        #print(index,authors)
        description_df = pd.DataFrame (authors, columns = ['author'])    

        titles.append(soup.find('title').get_text().split(' by ')[0])

        description_df['title'] = titles

        if soup.find('div',{'class':'readable stacked'}) is None:
            #print('This is a NoneType page:', url)
            description = soup.find('div',{'class':'TruncatedText__text TruncatedText__text--5'})
        else:
            description = soup.find('div',{'class':'readable stacked'}).get_text()
        urls.append(description)
        index += 1

        description_df['description'] = urls
        
    return(description_df)
```

To get the final dataframe I would call (as an example)

```
mystery_thriller_list = get_genre_url('mystery-thriller')
description_myster_thriller = get_description(mystery_thriller_list)
```

However, what I would like to get to is to pass the list of genres (for example `genres = ['fiction', 'mystery-thriller']`) into the functions and create the final dataframes for each genre where dataframe names would have naming convention description_'selected genre'.
So far I haven't figured it out and the for loop takes some time since it's loading information for 220 books for each genre.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the dataframes in a dictionary with the key as their genre names.

```
all_genres_descriptions = {}    
genres = ['fiction', 'mystery-thriller']
for genre in genres:
    genre_list = get_genre_url(genre)
    description_genre = get_description(genre_list)
    all_genres_descriptions[f'description_{genre}'] = description_genre
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things. For testing, you don't need to run through all years and books. I'm looking at just one year and the first two books. To do what you are looking for, you can use globals(). You might also just want to create one dataframe but add a column 'genre' to each iteration and concatenate. It may be easier in the long run to have all the data in one dataframe.

```
genres = ['fiction', 'mystery-thriller']
for genre in genres:
    mystery_thriller_list = get_genre_url(genre)
    globals()[f"{genre.replace('-', '_')}_selected_genre"] = get_description(mystery_thriller_list)

print(fiction_selected_genre)


author  title   description
0   Haruki Murakami 1Q84 (1Q84 #1-3)    \nThe year is 1984 and the city is Tokyo.A you...
1   Sarah Addison Allen The Peach Keeper    \nThe New York Times bestselling author of The...

print(mystery_thriller_selected_genre)


author  title   description
0   Janet Evanovich | Goodreads Smokin' Seventeen (Stephanie Plum, #17) [[[<p><b><i>Where there’s smoke there’s fire, ...
1   J.D. Robb   New York to Dallas (In Death, #33)  \nTwelve years ago, Eve Dallas was just a rook...
```